# SwiftUI "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, stopwatch

I'm trying to make this stopwatch app and designed the basic UI in the contentView file but used this class file for Stopwatch functions I found [here](https://gist.github.com/programmingwithswift/0303decba01bba1189e66d4943dda4a3).
I'm getting the "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" error in this part:

```
  private func resumeTimer() {
        self.sourceTimer?.setEventHandler {
            self.updateTimer()
        }

        self.sourceTimer?.schedule(deadline: .now(),
                                   repeating: 0.01)
        self.sourceTimer?.resume() // GETTING ERROR HERE
    }
```

This error doesn't show up in the BuildTime and RunTime but when I press the button which calls the start function in the simulator. And it doesn't even start the stopwatch and **when I press that button twice it gives this error**.

Can someone please tell me why the stopwatch is not starting and why am I getting this error?
I'm fairly new to Swift and SwiftUI. If it help my content view file was in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861794/unable-to-infer-complex-closure-return-type-add-explicit-type-to-disambiguate)

Comment: That's a pretty scrappy implementation. Repeated uses of `?.` like that are pretty nasty. Each one is like its own `if let sourceTimer = self.sourceTimer { sourceTimer.doSomething }`, which means each one may or may not do anyhting, depending on how the value of `self.sourceTimer` changes. It's better do do one `guard let`/`if let` statement to unwrap, and call the methods normally, on a non-optional `Timer` value.